# Printing a particular key's value of a python dictionary into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
> {'Target_Table': 'scott  .  employees',
 'Target_Columns': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id',
 'Source_Columns': 'emp_id    last_name    first_name    email    phone_number    JOB_DATE    job_id    salary    commission_pct    manager_id    department_id',
 'Source_Table': 'scott  .  employee',
 'where_expr': 'emp_id  =  old_emp_id'}
```

I have to print **Target_Columns values** each in a different row. So far they are all printing in one single row.
I know how to split words but I'm unable to perform it particularly on **Target_Columns key's values**.

```
> 'Target_Columns': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id'
```

Expected output:

```
>     Target Columns

>        empp_id
       last_name 
       first_name
       email 
       phone_number 
       JOB_DATE  ...
```

```
with open("proc.txt", 'r') as file:   
    if re.search(r'select|SELECT', file.read()):
        selr = select_stmt.parseString(open('proc.txt').read());
        sd=selr.asDict()
        sdict={k: str(v).strip("[]").replace("'", "").replace(","," ").replace("["," ").replace("]"," ") for k, v in sd.items()}
        val=sdict.values()
        for key in sdict:
            if key=='Target_Columns':
                for value in re.findall(r'\S+', val):
                    print(value)
```

Then for CSV I have this: I have no idea how to integrate both

```
with open('procfile.csv', 'w') as f: 
    fieldnames = ["Source_Table","Source_Columns","Target_Table","Target_Columns"]
    fieldnames = sorted(set(sd.keys()).union(*[sdict,idict]))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore') 
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(sdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sdict` is the dictionary you mentioned at the beginning of your question:

```
sdict = {'Target_Table': 'scott  .  employees',
         'Target_Columns': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id',
        }

for key, val in sdict.items():
    if key == 'Target_Columns':
        print(key)
        print("\n".join(val.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
sdict = {'Target_Table': 'scott  .  employees',
         'Target_Columns': 'empp_id  last_name  first_name  email  phone_number  JOB_DATE  job_id  salary  commission_pct  manager_id  department_id',
         }

print('\n'.join(sdict['Target_Columns'].split('  ')))
```